# UIButton Image is not changed in Hightlight or Selected state

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I wrote the following code of a button for an iOS8 app:

```
     UIButton *btnBack = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btnBack setFrame:CGRectMake(40, 30, 30, 30)];
    [btnBack setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_close.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnBack setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_close_on.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted|UIControlStateSelected];
    [btnBack addTarget:self action:@selector(btnBackClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:btnBack];
```

And the method when click:

```
-(void) btnBackClick:(id)sender{
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

However, the background of the image does not change when the button is being click. The only effect is the grayout.

If I draw that button on a xib file, the image change works like a charm.

Anything wrong? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UIButton *btnBack = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btnBack setFrame:CGRectMake(40, 30, 30, 30)];
[btnBack setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_close.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnBack setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_close_on.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted|UIControlStateSelected];
[btnBack addTarget:self action:@selector(btnBackClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[btnBack setSelected:YES];
[self.view addSubview:btnBack];
```

//**********Updated*******

```
UIButton *btnBack = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btnBack setFrame:CGRectMake(40, 30, 30, 30)];
[btnBack setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_close.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnBack setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_close_on.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[btnBack setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_close_on.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[btnBack addTarget:self action:@selector(btnBackClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:btnBack];

-(void)btnBackClick:(UIButton *)btn
{
    if ([btn isSelected])
    {
        [btn setSelected:NO];
    }
    else
        [btn setSelected:YES];
}
```

Comment: This magically works like a charm. Thank you very much. Could you explain why, please?

Comment: Actually Its not the right process to check a enum value(UIControlState). So, at first I have made the button in selected state. Please check my updated answer for it. It is more valuable then previous one.

Comment: The trick is: even though you initialize the button and setSelected:YES but the button still return to normal state when being added into view. So your original suggested code works.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void) btnBackClick:(id)sender{
   UIButton *myButton = (UIButton *)sender;

   [myButton setSelected: YES]; // Add this line
   [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 }
```

Also in viewWillAppear method set the same as NO

```
[myButton setSelected: NO]; // Add this line
```

Comment: Thank you. I have tried this as a search result here before submitting the question. It is still not working.